# PHP call_user_func a namespace alias

Tags: php, namespaces, alias

I'm wondering if it's possible to call a function from a name spaced file.

Currently the code below produces an error. I know it's possible to just pass the whole namespace, but is there a more automated way just using the alias of U?

`use Helpers\User as U;
 $t = call_user_func('U\something', 'test');
 var_dump($t);`

UPDATE

The way I solved this was by creating a function within that name spaced file that would return the file name spaced.

```
/**
 *
 * pntfn = Prepend namespace to function name
 *
 * @param $fn
 *
 * @return string
 */
function _pntfn($fn) {
    return __NAMESPACE__.'\\'.$fn;
}
```

This then let's me do the following in a file

```
use Helpers\Users as U;
```

If I wanted to compose (functional programming) a function from my Users namespace file I would do the following;

```
$get_username_upper = F\compose('strtoupper', U\_pntfn( 'get_username' ));
```

Not my favorite implementation, but works for now. The con, is that you'd have to add this to all of your name spaced function files.

Comment: Since there's no way can do this, what I did is to use `$U = 'Helpers\User'` then `call_user_func("$U\something", 'test')`.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is `U` is resolved at compile time, so calling:

```
U\something
```

Literally becomes:

```
Helpers\User\something
```

This might still be invalid, since I know we also have the directive `use function`, so you may want to check that out as well.

Anyway, the string `'U\something'` is a runtime constant, meaning `U` at this point doesn't actually refer to anything at all.  So no, unfortunately this isn't possible.